# scientific notation to normal decimal output conversion

Tags: php, number-formatting

First of all, I have tried a lot to find exactly the same question but failed. There were similar solutions and solutions that looks nice but not for me.

In PHP, I want to convert(or properly print out) a number to page with `echo` or something like that.

The input numbers may vary like that:

> 100000000
>
> 10
>
> 0.1
>
> 0.0000000001
>
> 100000000.0000000001

They are retrieved from MySQL database. The field format is `double`

But, when I try to `echo` those numbers, small decimal number is printed with scientific notation

> 1E-11

I found out `sprintf`, `number_format`, `stringfication`, make (`double`), or (`string`) etc.. but they have some unwanted functions like below:

1. rounding number
2. redundant 0(zero) tailing : eg) 0.1 to 0.10000

I simply want to printout those number *AS IS*

and without redundant processes.
(like convert to decimal format by number_format followed by making it string then remove zero tailings)

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it myself and I am posting a quick answer.

```
function realval($v) {
    $f = (string)number_format($v, 10, '.', ''); // 10000.0000010000
    if(strpos($f, '.') !== false) { // if it's a decimal (if not, print as is)
        $f = rtrim($f, "0"); // 10000.000001
        $f = rtrim($f, "."); // to prevent 10000. like things. 
    }
    return $f; // string format
}
```

This does what I needed. I wanted a more decent way to do so, but not figured out yet.

Comment: Use sprintf("%.8f", $v) where 8 - numbers required after the point